# PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_AWM' must be declared on owbsys user

Tags: database, oracle

After upgrading oracle database from 11gR1 to 11gR2, owbsys user's procedure get the following compilation error.

> PROCEDURE OWBSYS.WB_OLAP_LOAD_CUBE
> On line:  1
> PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_AWM' must be declared

Procedure Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OWBSYS.WB_OLAP_LOAD_CUBE(olap_aw_owner VARCHAR2, olap_aw_name VARCHAR2, olap_cube_owner VARCHAR2, olap_cube_name VARCHAR2, olap_tgt_cube_name VARCHAR2) AS     v varchar2(32);     
BEGIN     
    BEGIN       
        DBMS_AWM.CREATE_AWCUBELOAD_SPEC(olap_cube_name, olap_cube_owner, olap_cube_name, 'LOAD_DATA');     
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;     
    END;      
    DBMS_AWM.REFRESH_AWCUBE(olap_aw_owner, olap_aw_name, olap_tgt_cube_name, olap_cube_name);       
    DBMS_AW.EXECUTE('upd '||olap_aw_owner||'.'||olap_aw_name ||'; commit');     
    BEGIN     
        SELECT null into v from all_olap2_aw_cube_agg_specs where aw_owner=olap_aw_owner and aw_name=olap_aw_name and aw_cube_name=olap_tgt_cube_name and aw_aggspec_name=olap_cube_name;     
    EXCEPTION       
        WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN;     
    END;    
    DBMS_AWM.AGGREGATE_AWCUBE(olap_aw_owner, olap_aw_name, olap_tgt_cube_name, olap_cube_name);     
EXCEPTION       
    WHEN OTHERS THEN         RAISE;     
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the workaround to fix the issue

Step 1: Login to database as SYSDBA

Step 2: Run the following grant command

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_AWM TO OWBSYS;
```

Step 3: Re-compile your procedure.

Hopefully, after performing the above actions, your procedure will compile without errors.